# Linux X-Loader start address in config.mk instead of linker script

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, beagleboard

I have a question about how to specify the start address of code using gcc tools. 
I ussualy use the linker script to specify the start address of my code:

```
SECTIONS
{
   .  =  0x10000;
   .text  :  {  *(.text)  }
   .  =  0x8000000;
   .data  :  {  *(.data)  }
   .bss  :  {  *(.bss)  }
}
```

while analyzing the TI X-Loader (for beagleboard), I saw that in the x-load.lds the start address is put to 0x00000000. The correct start address is specified by "-Ttext 0x40200800" (RAM) in the config.mk file as a LD option.

My question: why use the -Ttext in the config.mk (LDFLAGS) instead of specifying it in the linker script?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards, Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, essentially because of same reason as avoiding any hardcoded values — it's more easy to parametrize.

Additionally, you don't have to dig in the linker script, so it's easier for newcomers.

If you're looking for some "principal" reason — there is not one.